# Using .htaccess, how do I reserve GET data when redirecting to one page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I want to have `url/main.php` to redirect to `url/index?page=main`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to preserve GET data. I.e. `url/main.php?foo=bar` redirects to `url/index?page=main`, when I would like it to redirect to `index.php?page=main&foo=bar`

Here's what I currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect /page.php, /page.html, and /page.htm to /page
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(php|html|htm)\/*$ /$1 [R,L]
# If the page is not a file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Internally redirect /page to /index.php?page=page
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,END]
# Redirect /index to /
Redirect /index /
```

Comment: Even if it is easily done with mod_rewrite, most rewrite questions are [XY-Problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and could be done in a more performant way. Are you dependend on existing code expecting the `$_GET['page']` parameter? Consider e.g. [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link right here is almost 100% made for your question and I'm pretty sure you'll find it does exactly what your looking for.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

This is the rule

```
RewriteRule "/pages/(.+)" "/page.php?page=$1" [QSA]
```

> With the [QSA] flag, a request for /pages/123?one=two will be mapped
>   to /page.php?page=123&one=two. Without the [QSA] flag, that same
>   request will be mapped to /page.php?page=123 - that is, the existing
>   query string will be discarded.